# Implementing @react-native-firebase/messaging with expo-router

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-router

I've set up a React Native project with expo-router and aim to integrate push notifications using @react-native-firebase/messaging. According to the [Firebase documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage):

> To setup a background handler, call the setBackgroundMessageHandler
> outside of your application logic as early as possible:

```
// index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App);
```

However, due to my project's configuration with expo-router, the app's entry point is now expo-router/entry (as mentioned in package.json):

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  ...
}
```

Considering this, where would be the appropriate place in my setup to include the background handler code snippet?

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

> When a file is created in the app directory, it automatically becomes a route in the app. For example, the following files will create the following routes.

So your routes will be something like this:

- `app/index.js` matches `/`
- `app/home.js` matches `/home`
- `app/settings/index.js` matches `/settings`
- `app/[user].js` matches dynamic paths like `/expo` or `/evanbacon`

In this case you'll need to put firebase background handler in your root `index.js` wich your app's first route `/`. See this example:

```
// index.js

... imports

// Register background handler outside component logic but
// stills as early as possible as this is the first page
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

function MyApp() {
  
  ... some content

 return (<>My App Content</>)
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/create-pages/).

Comment: I edited my question to quote the original instruction from react-native firebase documentation. `setBackgroundMessageHandler` has to be called outside of the application logic, which is before `AppRegistry.registerComponent(...);` is called.

Comment: You can still  use `index.js` file as it is your project's root file but in this case you'll set background handler outside your component's logic. I've edited my answer with an example.